# App crashes after i delete sceneview nodes

Tags: swift, xcode, arkit, sceneview

I added a button to my SceneView to delete placed images on a wall:

```
@IBAction func reset(_ sender: Any) {
sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, _) in node.removeFromParentNode()
    }
}
```

It's working fine but after some seconds the app crashed with following warning:

> com.apple.scenekit.scnview-renderer (14): Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

In this part of my code appears the error:

```
    func update(anchor: ARPlaneAnchor) {

    planeGeometry.width = CGFloat(anchor.extent.x);

    planeGeometry.height = CGFloat(anchor.extent.z);

    position = SCNVector3Make(anchor.center.x, 0, anchor.center.z);



    let planeNode = self.childNodes.first!

    planeNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: self.planeGeometry, options: nil))

}
```

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `let planeNode = self.childNodes.first!` you force unwrapping the value. After removing all nodes from `childNodes` array, it will become empty. Use `if let`

```
if let planeNode = self.childNodes.first{
 planeNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: self.planeGeometry, options: nil))
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Such a little mistake and everything is crashing. Thanks!